# Категоризация столбца по уникальным значениям

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Итак есть столбец значений (не числовых!) и в соответствии с определенной системой нужно поставить в соседнем столбце цифровое значение
Например:

```
RANK
   A
   B
   C
   D
```

Пусть у нас есть такое соответствие для второго столбца RANK2
`A=0.5 , B=1, C=1.5, D=2`
Соответственно на выходе надо получить

```
RANK  RANK2
A  0.5
B  1
C  1.5
D  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вспользуйтесь методом [Series.map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Serie.map.html).

Исходный DF:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
  RANK
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
```

Решение:

```
In [3]: mapping = dict(A=0.5, B=1, C=1.5, D=2)

In [4]: df['RANK2'] = df['RANK'].map(mapping)
```

Результат:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
  RANK  RANK2
0    A    0.5
1    B    1.0
2    C    1.5
3    D    2.0
```